# How to download files while creating them in realtime in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

Is there a PHP script where I can download a file while I am creating it in PHP?

The problem is that I have a huge script in PHP that creates a file, and to generate it, it lasts about 5 minutes. After it generates it, it downloads it, here takes another 5 mins or so.

In total it takes more than 10 minutes to download a file.

What I need is to create a script somewhat like phpmyadmin where the file downloads while it is being created.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

PS: I am using Codeigniter Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn the right terminology. Users download files. Web applications *serve* files. Without using proper terminology, and with no code, its hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: As developerwjk said. I will only add that, as far as I know, no file can be sent from PHP unless it's fully completed. Or I am really missing something.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I thought there could be a way or maybe make it faster to download regarding my problem. Thank you Forien for your answer.

Comment: i'm not sure if this will help but looks interesting https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Download-helper-for-large-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are creating that file, a full example would be very helpful.

But basically you need to set the correct headers and then you can start outputting the result as it gets created, line by line.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"'); 

for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
    echo $i . "\r\n";
    sleep(1);
}

exit;
```

The download prompt will be displayed immediately but downloading the file would take at least 20 seconds.

You should probably set the headers to the correct mime type, depending on what you intend to do.

Keep in mind that in your case the size of the download isn't available so the user won't know how big the file is or how much there is left to download. This is a drawback and there is basically nothing you can do if the file isn't already created.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I am looking for. I will take a look at it and get back to you. Thank you very much changepicture.